# varargs and the '...' argument

Tags: java, arrays, parameters, variadic-functions

Consider the method declaration:

```
String.format(String, Object ...)
```

The `Object ...` argument is just a reference to an array of `Object`s. **Is there a way to use this method with a reference to an actual `Object` array?** If I pass in an `Object` array to the `...` argument - will the resultant argument value be a two-dimensional array - because an `Object[]` is itself an `Object`:

```
Object[] params = ....; // Make the array (for example based on user-input)
String s = String.format("%S has %.2f euros", params);
```

So the first component of the array (Which is used in the `String.format` method), will be an array and he will generate:

```
[class.getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())]
```

and then an error because the array size is 1.

The **bold** sequence is the real question.
This is a second question: **Does a `...` array/parameter have a name?**

Comment: Sorry, I had to test it before asking... I think I had this problem a long time ago.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

From the [docs on varargs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html):

> The three periods after the final
>   parameter's type indicate that the
>   final argument may be passed as an
>   array or as a sequence of arguments.

So you can pass multiple arguments or an array.

The following works just fine:

```
class VarargTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[] params = {"x", 1.2345f};
    String s = String.format("%s is %.2f", params);
    System.out.println(s); // Output is: x is 1.23
  }
}
```

Comment: So if you want to call the method with a single argument and it happens to be an array, you have to explicitly wrap it in another. `method(new Object[]{array});`

Comment: or do `method((Object)array)`, which will auto-wrap

Comment: I'm better off than before I saw these explanations about vararg parameters, yet I still just don't get it.

Answer (score 11):

You can just pass an array:

```
public void foo(String... args) {
}

String args[] = new String[10];
foo(args);
```

Comment: I'm not going to even bother adding my own answer, edit in "... is known as vararg or variable arguments and requires 0..n elements of specified elements" or something like that.

Answer (score 7):

The situation you are describing is going to be fairly rare: most of the time, your varargs items will be `String`s, or numbers, or `Widget`s... it will be unusual for them to be `Object`s (which could be anything) or arrays.

But if the varargs argument **is** a bunch of `Object`s or an array type, then your question does arise: you can pass it a single array and then how will the compiler know whether you meant to pass an array (the one you provided), or an series of 1 item which it should PUT into an array for you?

A quick test shows the answer:

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object anObject = new Object();
        Object[] anArray = new Object[] {anObject, anObject};
        System.out.println("object1 = " + anObject);
        System.out.println("array1 = " + anArray);
        takesArgs();
        takesArgs(anObject, anObject);
        takesArgs(anArray); // is this the same as array1?
        takesArgs(anArray, anArray);
    }

    public static void takesArgs(Object... stuff) {
        System.out.println("The array was " + stuff);
    }
}
```

The result of executing (your exact numbers will vary:

```
object1 = java.lang.Object@3e25a5
array1 = [Ljava.lang.Object;@19821f
The array was [Ljava.lang.Object;@addbf1
The array was [Ljava.lang.Object;@42e816
The array was [Ljava.lang.Object;@19821f
The array was [Ljava.lang.Object;@9304b1
```

So the answer is that in ambiguous cases it treats what you passed as the array instead of creating a new array to wrap it. This makes sense as you could always wrap it in an array yourself if you wanted the other interpretation.