# Why is it not allowed in Java to overload Foo(Object...) with Foo(Object[])?

Tags: java, methods, parameters, arguments, language-specifications

I was wondering why it is not allowed in Java to overload `Foo(Object[] args)` with `Foo(Object... args)`, though they are used in a different way?

```
Foo(Object[] args){}
```

is used like:

```
Foo(new Object[]{new Object(), new Object()});
```

while the other form:

```
Foo(Object... args){}
```

is used like:

```
Foo(new Object(), new Object());
```

Is there any reason behind this?

Comment: I may be missing something, but why do you need an overload?  If you declare your method as `void foo(Object... args)` then you can call it with **either** `foo(new Object(), new Object())` **or** `foo(new Object[] { new Object(), new Object() })` and get the same result.  See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656901/varargs-and-the-argument) for an example.

Comment: the vararg is just a flag to the method signature transmuting the last declared array (like `int[]` or `Object[]`) to vararg type. Other than that - no difference between the method signatures.  The same question would be like can't overload `private` and `public` method.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This [15.12.2.5 Choosing the Most Specific Method](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#301183) talk about this, but its quite complex. e.g. Choosing between Foo(Number... ints) and Foo(Integer... ints)

In the interests of backward compatibility, these are effectively the same thing.

```
public Foo(Object... args){} // syntactic sugar for Foo(Object[] args){}

// calls the varargs method.
Foo(new Object[]{new Object(), new Object()});
```

e.g. you can define main() as

```
public static void main(String... args) {
```

---

A way to make them different is to take one argument before the varargs

```
public Foo(Object o, Object... os){} 

public Foo(Object[] os) {}

Foo(new Object(), new Object()); // calls the first.

Foo(new Object[]{new Object(), new Object()}); // calls the second.
```

---

They are not exactly the same.  The subtle difference is that while you can pass an array to a varargs, you can't treat an array parameter as a varargs.

```
public Foo(Object... os){} 

public Bar(Object[] os) {}

Foo(new Object[]{new Object(), new Object()}); // compiles fine.

Bar(new Object(), new Object()); // Fails to compile.
```

Additionally, a varags must be the last parameter.

```
public Foo(Object... os, int i){} // fails to compile.

public Bar(Object[] os, int i) {} // compiles ok.
```

Comment: +1 nice explanation. Is there any language specifications written for this?

Comment: Have a look on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14937948/597657) please.

Answer (score 3):

The most direct answer to the question is that having both declarations would create an ambiguity in the method lookup logic. If you declared both in the same class, there would be no way to figure out which method you wanted when calling thusly:

```
Object[] a = new Object[10];
Foo(a); // array or vararg?
```

And Java requires that there always be a most specific method for every method invocation.
For the *why*, see Peter's answer.

Comment: they are *exactly* the same, not ambiguity, they just can't exist in the same class