# Wrapper's parseXXX() for signed binary misunderstanding

Tags: java, parsing, binary, api-design

Let's take `Byte.parseByte()` as an example as one of the wrappers' `parseXXX()`.

From [`parseByte(String s, int radix)'s JavaDoc`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#parseByte%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> Parses the string argument as a signed byte in the radix specified by
>   the second argument.

But that's not quite true if `radix = 2`. In other words, the binary literal of `-127` is `10000000`:

```
byte b = (byte) 0b10000000;
```

So the following should be true:

```
byte b = Byte.parseByte("10000000", 2);
```

but unfortunately, it throws `NumberFormatException`, and instead I have to do it as follows:

```
byte b = Byte.parseByte("-111111", 2);
```

where `parseByte()` parses the binary string as a sign-magnitude (the sign and the magnitude), where it should parse as a signed binary (2's complement, i.e. MSB is the sign-bit).

Am I wrong about this?

Comment: Research: Have you looked at the source code?

Comment: @jlordo No, I haven't yet.

Comment: Do it, that's how I understood this whole problem yesterday before posting [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926920/java-long-parse-binary-string/14927505#14927505).

Comment: @jlordo: It's not necessary to look at the source code; the behaviour is explicitly documented in the Javadocs.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I agree, but the use of the term _signed byte_ **can** be misleading and is the reason for this question (I think).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I wrong about this?

Yes.  The Javadoc says nothing about 2's-complement.  Indeed, it explicitly states how it recognises negative values (i.e. a `-` prefix, so effectively "human-readable" sign-magnitude).

Think about it another way.  If `parseByte` interpreted radix-2 as 2's-complement, what would you want it to do for radix-10 (or indeed, any other radix)?  For consistency, it would have to be 10's-complement, which would be inconvenient, I can assure you!

Comment: I would also note that JavaDoc uses the term _signed byte_ to emphasize that Java doesn't know unsigned bytes.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: They could, but then that would be (a) inconsistent and (b) undocumented ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is because for parseByte "10000000" is a positive value (128) which does not fit into byte values range -128 to 128. But we can parse two's comlement binary string representation with BigInteger:

```
byte b = new BigInteger("10000000", 2).byteValue()
```

this gives expected -128 result