# How does overload resolution work with a null argument?

Tags: java

Why is the method with a parameter of type `Object[]` called rather than the method with a parameter of type `Object` when `null` is passed as the argument?

```
class Demo {
    void show(Object arr[]) {
        System.out.println("khawar");
    }

    public void show(Object o) {
        System.out.println("aleem");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Demo ss=new Demo();
        ss.show(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is it not allowed in Java to overload Foo(Object...) with Foo(Object\[\])?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838339/why-is-it-not-allowed-in-java-to-overload-fooobject-with-fooobject)

Comment: because it is closer in hierarchy

Comment: As an aside, `void show(Object arr[])` would be more idiomatically written as `void show(Object[] arr)` - keep the array part along with the rest of the type information.

Comment: I've edited the question significantly to make it a lot more readable. Please let me know if you object to any of the editing.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, it's important to note that the `null` value is convertible to both `Object` and `Object[]`, so both methods are *applicable*. Then it's just a matter of overload resolution. That's described in [section 15.12 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12), and [section 15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) in particular talks about finding "the most specific method", which includes:

> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time type error.

That's the case here: any invocation of `show(Object[])` can be passed to `show(Object)` without a compile-time type error, therefore `show(Object[])` is more specific than `show(Object)`, so overload resolution picks `show(Object[])` to invoke.

To invoke `show(Object)` you just have to cast the `null` to `Object`, to stop the `show(Object[])` method from being applicable:

```
ss.show((Object) null);
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to go through the JLS to find the exact explanation, but basically the reason is, that the most specific method signature is chosen, and "null" acts as a more specific match to subclasses than superclasses.

```
// Where Subclass extends Middleclass extends Superclass
public void method(Superclass c) {}
public void method(Middleclass m) {}
public void method(Subclass s) {}
```

In the above case, a call to `method(null)` would call `method(Subclass s)`.

Answer (score 0):

The most specific signature will be chosen when multiple candidates are matched. `Object[]` *is* an `Object`, therefore it is more specific where `Object` is more generic.

For instance, if you added `show(Integer[])` then this would be the most specific candidate, and will be chosen over `show(Object[])`. If you added both `show(Integer[])` and `show(String[])` then you will get a compile time error specifying `show(Object)` is ambiguous, because both of the new added methods are candidates of equal specificity towards the call you are trying to make.

If you wanted to force call `show(Object)` instead, then you could write: `show((Object)null);`