# Issue with SLF4J varargs Vs Arrays

Tags: slf4j

Why does org.slf4j.Logger use varargs like:

```
public void info(Marker marker, String format, Object... arguments);
```

But both org.slf4j.ext.LoggerWrapper and thus org.slf4j.cal10n.LocLogger use Arrays like:

```
public void info(Marker marker, String format, Object[] argArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

LoggerWrapper and LocLogger are compatible with varargs syntax when Java 5+ is used, but they are also compatible with Java < 5. The array syntax can be compiled and run under older versions of Java while still supporting varargs syntax when Java >= 5 is used.

The SLF4J API < 1.7 used array syntax. With API version 1.7, the varargs syntax was used, which means it cannot be used on Java versions < 5.

You might have a look at [varargs and the '...' argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656901/varargs-and-the-argument) for some more examples of how this works and why you might want to do it.