# How can I pass the Strings from an ArrayList<String> to a method that takes in multiple Strings?

Tags: android, string, arraylist, variadic-functions

I have got an ArrayList with Strings and a method that can take in any amount of strings as arguments.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
// Filling the list with strings...

public addStrings(String... args) {
    // Do something with those Strings
}
```

Now I would like to pass those strings from my array list to that method. How can I do that? How would I call `addStrings()` Note that the amount of strings in the arraylist can vary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
// Filling the list with strings...

    String[] stringArray = new String[list.size()];
    list.toArray(stringArray);
    addStrings(stringArray);

public addStrings(String... args) {
    // Do something with those Strings
}
```

Pass your strings in a primitive array. From the [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) documentation:

> The three periods after the final parameter's type indicate that the final argument may be passed as **an array or as a sequence of arguments**.

All you'd need to do is derive a `String[]` from your `List` and then pass it to the `addStrings(String... args)` method.

Credit to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656901/varargs-and-the-argument) question for the documentation link.

Comment: ok, but how should I implement this part `String s = String.format("%s,  %s, %s", strings);` if the number of arguments is only known at runtime.

Comment: That was only an example of a use of what I was talking about. I'll adapt my example to match your situation.