# Java "..." expression

Tags: java

I'm interested in what is this '...' expression in some codes, for example:

```
public static void main(String... args){
   //code here
}
```

This is valid (maybe lambda, i'm not sure).

I find it in Spring's Sort file too:

```
public Sort(Sort.Order... orders) {
    this(Arrays.asList(orders));
}
```

Somebody can help me?

Comment: this are [varargs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766559/when-do-you-use-varargs-in-java) and another [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656901/varargs-and-the-argument)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This idiom is not a lambda, it's called [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html) (short for variable arguments) and it's there since Java 5.

The functionality allows you to take an indeterminate number of parameters of the same type (or sub-types) at the end of a method's signature, once per method signature.

The arguments can then be handled as an array of that type.

Answer (score 1):

The "..." is "varargs": It accepts an arbitrary amount of String in first example and Orders in 2nd one.
Those methods does also accept arrays.